# how to iterate through files in directory excluding hidden files

Tags: shell, files, wildcards, dot-files

Using:

```
for eachfile in /mnt/thara/*
```

Which iterates through hidden files as well. I don't need hidden files.

Comment: shopt -u dotglob ?

Comment: Another way around it is: `ls /mnt/thara | while read i; do ... done`

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The normal behavior of bash is to do not look to the hidden files when using for. But this behavior can be changed with shopt command.

To enable the scanning for hidden files with "*":

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

To disable the scanning for hidden files with "*" (default behavior)

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

So try a script like this :

```
shopt -u dotglob
for eachfile in /mnt/thara/*
```

And now the hidden files must go away.

Answer (score 3):

Other way is

```
for eachfile in /mnt/thara/[^.]*
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment about the `dotglob` shell option.
If it is unset, the behavior of the for loop is the one expected:

```
utente@computer:/tmp/test$ shopt | grep dotglob
dotglob         off
```

Let `a`, `b`, and `c` are normal files; `.hidden1` and `.hidden2` hidden files:

```
utente@computer:/tmp/test$ touch a b c .hidden1 .hidden2

utente@computer:/tmp/test$ ls -al
totale 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 utente utente 4096 giu 10 18:28 .
drwxrwxrwt 13 root   root   4096 giu 10 18:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 utente utente    0 giu 10 18:28 a
-rw-rw-r--  1 utente utente    0 giu 10 18:28 b
-rw-rw-r--  1 utente utente    0 giu 10 18:28 c
-rw-rw-r--  1 utente utente    0 giu 10 18:28 .hidden1
-rw-rw-r--  1 utente utente    0 giu 10 18:28 .hidden2
```

---

For loop:

```
utente@computer:/tmp/test$ for eachfile in * ; do ls $eachfile ; done

a
b
c
```

---

Another way, independent from shell options: let's instruct `find` to filter out all pathnames whose initial charachters match the dot `.`:

```
utente@computer:/tmp/test$ find . \( ! -path '*/.*' \) -type f  -exec ls {} \;

./c
./b
./a
```

See also [this question](https://superuser.com/q/152958/334344) on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` command like this :

```
for file in $(find /mnt/thara/ -type f \( ! -iname ".*" \)) ; do ---something $file--- ; done`
```

Answer (score 0):

Or very simply..

```
ls -l | egrep -v "^\."
```

or to iterate all directories showing filenames:

```
ls -R | egrep -v "^\."
```

Comment: That will simply list the files - not iterate through them.

Comment: If you want to iterate through just file names without hidden files use -R

Comment: @garethTheRed is right; also "iterate through" != "recursively list."